# Why does cron job causes a memoey leak in Node.js pupeeter schdule?

Tags: node.js, unix, memory-leaks, cron, puppeteer

I'm running a puppeteer project on node.js.

When I run it manually like this:
`node project.js`
it works well, with no issues.
But when I schedule it with crontab like this:

```
* 0,8,16 * * * cd ~/project_folder/ && /usr/bin/node project.js >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The server memory get congestion to 100% and the app crashes, puppeteer gets errors `page crush`

You can see in this graph the manual vs the schedule:
[image: Memory]
[image: CPU]

Server errors:

[image: Server errors]

Also, when I run `ps -ef | grep node` l get loads of active services, too many to really point into one specific issue.

How do I tackle it?

Comment: can you tell me what is the business or why you need to use cron job?

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with puppeteer cause I did not terminate the browser instance when it gets idle. and you have to close the page if you finished your work with the page.

```
await page.close()
await browser.close()
```

suggestion:
for this purpose, you can use [puppeteer-cluster](http://await%20page.close()). cluster handles the rest of the memory management and concurrency stuff for you.

Comment: i do use `page.close()` and `browser.close()` and even `process.exit()` at the end of the app run. Also, as mentioned, this works well when I just run `node project.js` the issue is only with cronjob.

Comment: you running the puppeteer job with nodejs it self?I mean your program always running?

Comment: Nop, once the script is executed it takes 3-4 hours, and then it's done when it gets to the last code line. The cron job is with a simple crontab in the root user. I tried with node-cron - npm as well, but had similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the cronjob command is wrong.

This one:

`* 0,8,16 * * *`

runs the command every minute starting at 00:00,08:00,16:00. Manning, again and again, every minute.

This is the correct one that will run it once at the requested time (00:00, 08:00, 16:00):

```
0 0,8,16 * * *
```

`0` instead of `*`.

Here is a great website to check your cronjob commands:
[Crontab Guru](https://crontab.guru/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the memory leak has to do with crontab and puppeteer interacting.

When I ran my node/puppeteer app on the same ubuntu 18 server but using pm2 (--restart) instead of crontab, there was no memory leak over time (but pm2 has its own issues).

When I run the app with crontab, the server memory usage hits 100% after about 4 days (the app runs for 5 minutes every 10 minutes during the day).

`0,10,20,30,40,50 7-22 * * * /usr/local/bin/node ~/pptrapp/app.js >> ~/pptrapp/log 2>&1`

Thereafter, the log reads "Aborted (core dumped)" each time the app is launched by crontab.

I'm am using the workaround of killing any hanging processes 1 minute before each new puppeteer cronjob, like so:

`# kill all puppeteer and node before next run`

`9,19,29,39,49,59 7-22 * * * pkill -f puppeteer`

`9,19,29,39,49,59 7-22 * * * killall -9 node`